# Anko's execute the sqlite request but don't execute the next lines

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, anko

I want to make a request on my internal database on Android but when my request Anko is done, the lines present in the UiThread are not done immediately.

To explain what happens, the line "Log.d" is execute before the UiThread

Can you help me?

```
for(i in 0 until jsonArrayM.length()) {
        val json = jsonArrayM.getJSONObject(i)
        doAsync {
            val carteByName = bdd.getDatasByName(json.get("role").toString())
            uiThread {
                json.put("id", carteByName[0].id)
                json.put("image", carteByName[0].imageCarte)
                json.put("nuit1", carteByName[0].premiereNuit)
                json.put("posNuit1", carteByName[0].positionPremiereNuit)
                json.put("autresNuits", carteByName[0].nuitSuivante)
                json.put("posAutresNuits", carteByName[0].positionNuitSuivante)
            }
        }
        jsonArray.put(json)
    }
    Log.d("Verif", jsonArray.toString())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The block inside `doAsync` is done *asynchronously* in a background thread, and the block inside `uiThread` is done only at the end of your async block (but on the UI/Main thread).
The `Log`, on the other hand, is executed *synchronously* after the loop.
So it is expected that the code inside the async block is executed after the synchronous code.

Comment: Thanks Gpunto for your answer :) 
Yes I undestand but when I wan't to change Activity, my data is empty. So how can I solve this problem ??